# Green's function for the free particle Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

For a free particle in 1D, the equation for its Green function (in atomic units) is 
$$\left(E+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)G(x,x',E) = \delta(x-x')$$
The textbook I'm following says the solution is 
$$G(x,x',E) = \frac{1}{i(2E)^{1/2}} \exp(i (2E)^{1/2} \lvert x-x'\rvert),$$
but I'm not sure how it is derived. And even if I substitute this function back in, on the left hand side I got
$$\exp(i (2E)^{1/2} \lvert x - x' \rvert) \delta(x-x')$$
instead of just $\delta(x-x')$. Could any one help me on how to solve the differential equation?

Comment: Integrate with respect to $x'$ or $x$ and you will find the function behaves the same as $\delta(x-x')$. (This is called weak equivalence, if instead of equality $f(x)=g(x)$, $\langle f,h\rangle=\langle g,h\rangle$ for any function $h$ which is infinitely differentiable and goes to zero outside of a finite area. For actual functions you have equality, for things like delta functions you have weak equivalence, and it's why $\delta'(x)$ is well defined). To solve the equation, take the Fourier transform of both sides with respect to $x$, then do algebra to find $G(k,x',E)$, then transform back.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)\delta(x)=f(0)\delta(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with using Fourier transform to solve differential equations so got stuck. I searched online and now have some idea.